# Double integral of off centre circle.

Tags: calculus, integration, area, greens-theorem

I have the vector field $F = (3xy,-x)$ along the circle $c$ (counter clockwise) which has a radius $a$ and centre $(a,0)$.

I want to try and apply Green's Theorem to this, where I obtain $\int\int(-1 - 3x )dxdy$.

Now I try and use polar coordinates, where I replace $x = a + r\cos\theta$ and $dxdy =rdrd\theta$.

The limits of $r$ are from $0$ to $a$, and the limits of $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.
When I solve the integral I get $-a^{2}\pi - 3a^{3}\pi$ . Is this correct? I don't know the answer and im not entirely sure of my working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the integral as an average value, then
$$\int\int_Rf(x,y)d^2A=\langle f\rangle_R\times A(R)$$
that is the average value of the function $f$ over the region $R$ times the area of region $R$. The average value of $x$ is just the $x$-coordinate of the center of mass, $a$, and the average value of $1$ is $1$, so
$$\int\int_R(-1-3x)d^2A=(-1-3a)\cdot\pi a^2=-\pi a^2-3\pi a^3$$
You translated the origin of coordinates to $(a,0)$ but you could have chosen the parameterization $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\cos\theta$, $0\le r\le2a\cos\theta$ so that you might get
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{2a\cos\theta}(-1-3r\cos\theta)r\,dr\,d\theta&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}(-2a^2\cos^2\theta-8a^3\cos^4\theta)d\theta\\
&=-2a^2\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)-8a^3\left(\frac{3\pi}8\right)=-\pi a^2-3\pi a^3\end{align}$$
Where we have again used the average value of $\frac12$ for $\cos^2\theta$ and of $\frac38$ for $\cos^4\theta$.